# How can I find a button inside a div element searching by specific name in a row?

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-traversal

The page returns several records within a div element. I am trying to fetch the line that contains the name **Kiyara.Hu** and click on the respective edit button of that name.

I tried the command below but it didn't work.

```
cy.contains('div','Kiyara.Hu').find('button').click()
```

Below is the HTML code and screenshots of the site.

```html
<div class="oxd-table-cell oxd-padding-cell" role="cell">
  <div class="oxd-table-card-cell-checkbox">
    <div class="oxd-checkbox-wrapper" data-v-6179b72a=""><label class="" data-v-6179b72a=""><!----><input type="checkbox" value="22" data-v-6179b72a=""><span
      class="oxd-checkbox-input oxd-checkbox-input--active --label-right oxd-checkbox-input"
      data-v-6179b72a=""><i class="oxd-icon bi-check oxd-checkbox-input-icon"
          data-v-bddebfba="" data-v-6179b72a=""></i></span></label></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="oxd-table-cell oxd-padding-cell" role="cell" style="flex: 1 1 0%;">
  <div data-v-6c07a142="">Kiyara.Hu</div>
</div>
<div class="oxd-table-cell oxd-padding-cell" role="cell" style="flex: 1 1 0%;">
  <div data-v-6c07a142="">ESS</div>
</div>
<div class="oxd-table-cell oxd-padding-cell" role="cell" style="flex: 1 1 0%;">
  <div data-v-6c07a142="">Kiyara Hu</div>
</div>
<div class="oxd-table-cell oxd-padding-cell" role="cell" style="flex: 1 1 0%;">
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With so many divs in the picture, you will have to be more specific about which one your test needs to target.

Same with the button, since there are two per line.

I'm presuming the line in the table is represented by class `oxd-table-card`, if that's not the case you can re-examine the DOM to find the appropriate element.

```js
cy.contains('div.oxd-table-card', 'Kiyara.Hu')
  .find('button').eq(1)
  .click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it:

```
var divs = [...document.querySelectorAll("DIV")];
divs = divs.filter(function(a) {
  return a.innerText.includes('Kiyara.Hu');
});
//maybe check that your div has been found first, then
divs[0].querySelector("Button");
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. Displays the error message: divs.filter is not a function.

Comment: @Kakashi-Sensei I have updated my answer: I/You need to convert the NodeList (from querySelectorAll) to an Array.

Comment: Now it is showing the following error message: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'querySelector')

Comment: @Kakashi-Sensei 3rd time's the charm (I hope)

Comment: I couldn't understand your answer.

Comment: This code works now